# Composite Keys - number of key values passed in not same as number of keys in entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have looked at other questions and solutions and it seems I am doing everything right, at least in theory.  But I am getting the "number of key values passed in not the sames as number of keys in entity" when trying to find an object on one of my class objects.

Below is a part of my DbContext class:

```
public DbSet<KM_Codes_KCO> KCOs { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<KM_Codes_KCO>().HasKey(k => 
            new { k.KCO_RequestedServer, k.KCO_ServerPort, k.KCO_Code });
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Now the following code is how I am calling the find on the KCO object.

```
KMDBContext db = new KMDBContext();
KM_Codes_KCO kco = db.KCOs.Find(new { server, port, hashPassword });
```

The error occurs when I hit the `.Find` call.  All of the parameters are in the correct order and of the correct type.  I have to be missing something simple.

EDIT - ANSWER:

I have a knack for finding the problem after asking the question.  It should be `db.KCOs.Find(new object[] { server, port, hashPassword }));`   I put the `object[]` in and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`Find` has the signature `Find(params object[] keys)` which indeed means that you can pass an object array into the method `Find(new object[] { server, port, hashPassword })` - as you already found. But the `params` keyword allows the much simpler syntax to pass every array element as a separate parameter:

```
...Find(server, port, hashPassword)
```